# Encodings ([DrSNX][Мι¢ŕôśőƒŧ ₤ĿĐΡ Ρґŏţǿćǿł Ðѓїνєґ !!! !!! ]) what is this?

Tags: windows, encoding

I have an XML with the following information

```
<NetworkProtocol Name="[DrSNX][Мι¢ŕôśőƒŧ ₤ĿĐΡ Ρґŏţǿćǿł Ðѓїνєґ !!! !!! ]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[KdZ72][ЙĐĪŜ Ůšεѓмóďє Î/Ǿ Рґбτǿċôŀ !!! !!!]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[JbE1E][Ίйŧзяñèţ Ρѓøţòĉöļ Vεяśīθñ 6 (ŤÇΡ/ΊΡν6) !!! !!! !!]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[WA0qU][ЩİΝЅ Ĉŀΐęйŧ(ŢČΡ/ÎΡ) Рґоŧôĉòĺ !!! !!!]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[0ANYk][Мęŝšãğє-őřîēňť℮ď ŢĈР/ĨΡ Рŗοŧŏ¢ŏĺ (ŜМВ ѕëśѕíоⁿ) !!! !!! !!! !]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[vgSqW][Ĭήţеґŋέт Ρяότσçοℓ (ТČР/İР) - Тūŉπêĺš !!! !!! !!]"/>
<NetworkProtocol Name="[6oxNG][Ρòîŉт ťŏ Рőíńť Рŗоťõčøł Ονèŗ Зтђēŗňêτ !!! !!! !!]"/>
```

It's from a machine running a preview build of the Windows 6.3 kernel but I have no idea what type of encoding this is, it's very readable but I don't have the slightest idea how some which originates from Windows ends up like this? Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [pseudo-localized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudolocalization) text, automatically generated to test that the software displays non-ASCII characters correctly while still keeping it readable to English speakers.

Apparently some beta versions of Windows have been [released with pseudo-localized components](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/07/07/engineering-windows-7-for-a-global-market.aspx), probably by accident.

Comment: Do you know if this is something Microsoft does in it's preview builds?

Comment: NVM - the Wikipedia article is very helpful

Comment: I don't think they do it on purpose, but it has happened.

Comment: From what we could tell in our tests, this was not consistent across all builds of Windows 8.1 preview and Windows Server 2012 R2, there were differences in the 32-bit builds of Windows 8.1 as well